# JAXB Annotated class - setting of a variable which is not an element

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a JAXB annotated class say

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.abc.com/customer")
Class Customer{
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.abc.com/customer")
  private String  Name;
  @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.abc.com/customer")
  private String  Address;
 @XmlTransient
  private HashSet set = new HashSet();

  public String getName(){
    return Name;
  }
  public void  setName(String  name){
    this.Name = name;
    set.add("Name");
  }


  public String getAddress(){
    return Address;
  }
  public void  setAddress(String  address){
    this.Address = address;
    set.add("Address");
  }

  public void getSet(){
return set;
}
```

I have a XML of the form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Customer xmlns="http://www.abc.com/customer" >
<Name>Ralph</Name>
<Address>Newton Street</Address>
</Customer>
```

I use JAXB unmarshalling to get the object representation of the XML input. The values for Name and Address are set correctly. However 
the value of set gets lost(since it is @XMLTransient it gets ignored)

Is there any way of ensuring that it is still set in the object which has been unmarshalled? Some other annotation which I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the annotations on the methods rather than on the fields. Specifically, put `@XmlElement` on `getName()` and `getAddress()`, put `@XmlTransient` on `getSet()`, and remove all the annotations from the fields.

JAXB should then use the getter/setter method pairs to inject/retrieve the data, rather than the fields, and because `setAddress()` adds the value to the `set` field, that should work as you expect. Also, because `getSet()` is marked as transient, the contents of `set` should not be marshalled again.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the solution. I tried this one, but none of the XML element values are being set(Name, Address) Is it a valid case to add these annotations to the methods?

Comment: @sswdeveloper: It is valid, yes, but sometimes you have to juggle things a bit. Try annotating the setter methods rather than the getter methods.

Answer (score 2):

To Avoid all this boiler plate code of XmLElement annotation all over the code. You can go ahead and use `@XmlAccessType.PROPERTY` at the top of the class and you can go remove all the `@XmlElement` Annotations. The XmlAccessType annotation takes care of telling JAXB to look at the setters and getters and not the field itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using some post-processor utility to fill your set. Perhaps using reflection or introspection.

Note that the postprocessor will have to inspect the JAXB annotations only, not the xml file.

Comment: I could do that, but the set contains only those elements which have been set in the XML, not any other elements. So doing a post processing would involve parsing the XML again and then setting the values/reading all class members and checking if they have been set.
However this eliminates the whole point of using JAXB and would be a performance hit. Is there any other alternative using JAXB itsef?
Thanks.

Comment: @sswdeveloper no, the postprocessing will include parsing the JAXB annotations only.